# How to set vertical page indicators in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have tried below code to set vertical page indicators in a view controller

```
self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical options:nil];

self.pageController.dataSource = self;
[[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
```

I am able to scroll vertically with this code, however, dots are not getting displayed if I set navigationOrientation like this:

```
navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical
```

[image: How to develop vertical page indicators as shown in the below image:]

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, where you setup the `pageControl`, add:

```
pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
```